# Error while Jekyll on Mac OSX missing header files

Tags: ruby, macos, jekyll

I'm trying to install Jekyll on my Mac OSX but I keep getting an error when I type in *gem install jeykll* I get this error that says that it can't find the header files. Does anyone know how to fix this error because I've looked around online and keep getting different answer .

Here is the message on terminal:

> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby -r
>   ./siteconf20140821-18027-7kqerk-0.rb extconf.rb mkmf.rb can't find
>   header files for ruby at
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

On OSX, you may need to update RubyGems:

```
sudo gem update --system
```

You can get useful information from official website (http://jekyllrb.com/docs/troubleshooting/)